# Modify VisualStudio Generated files, to parse true/false to existance of a XML element

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, web-services, xml-parsing

Our company provide software for a massive network, with variety of languages and applications. and here's where i stuck.

We accept to implement a service based application for one of our customers, and after basic setup, and gain access to basic data, i received error while sending data ( i'm not sure if the data i receive are correct either.

The host server, require boolean to be in following format (for example within X object)

```
<X>
  <Y/>
</X>
```

Mean Y is: True

```
<X>
  <Y/>
</X>
```

Mean Y is: False

But the C# web service Generate it in following order:

```
<X>
  <Y>true</Y>
</X>
```

For True and

```
<X>
  <Y>false</>
</X>
```

For false.

How should i modify it to provide that functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS studio also some little configuration while creating service reference when you move to advanced tab... also be careful of the enums, some time you need to also specify that you specify the enum, it is not marked as nullable, and if you do not chnage the XSpecified flag, for X enum, it wont get generated through the sending XML request...